# Как обновить Gradle в Android StudIo?

Tags: android

Читал на английском StackOverlow. и на Хабре .Там говорят что стабильная версия gradle это 2.4 Типо из за нее сборка приходит от 10-20 сек.

У меня сборка идет больше минуты.

4 ядра * 3000
12 гигов оперативы.

Железо не причем. Поэтому вина всему Gradle. Говорят от 2.1 градл все медленнее. А уже с 2.4 все баги и ошибки пофикшены.

Вместо 2 минуты стало 10-20 сек.

Скажите. Почему Android Studio не позволяет обновиться до 2.4. Так как на сайте у них написанно самая стабильная это 2.1. Чем они там думают.

И как можно обновиться в Androi Studio до 2.4. А лучше вообще в 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Версия сборщика и версия Gradle немного разные понятия. Я может оперирую не теми названиями, но текущая версия Gradle по моему 2.14, а сборщика соответствует версии Вашей Android Studio - 2.1.

Чтобы обновить gradle надо либо в файле gradle.wrapper в Вашем проекте поменять версию на актуальную и указать в настройках, что gradle обновляется удаленно - кажется это стоит по умолчанию (то есть в настройках делать ничего не нужно), либо скачать с оф сайта последнюю версию и в настрйоках указать ее расположение.

Что касается скорости сборки - не уверен, что она будет происходить сильно быстрее.

И не сколько важна RAM, сколько процессор, а так же частота RAM и ее тайминги. Я в свое время увеличил объем памяти вдвое, что вообще никак не отразилось на скорости сборки. Зато на MacOS с более "умным" механизмом управления памятью при том же объёме памяти и даже меньшей ее частоте - все работает существенно быстрее

Comment: [текущая версия](https://gradle.org/gradle-download/) системы сборки Gradle - 3.0. [Текущая стабильная версия](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle) плагина Gradle для AS - 2.1.3, [последняя](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view) - 2.2.0 beta3.